# Angular 4 Typescript using json instead of class variables

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Currently, I am getting data from the db using an Angular Service and then using this data in my component to interact with the template. (The data is properly stored in a typed object and of course, I've got a instance of this object on the controller) What I am doing is using the same object for storing temporal data for example save ids, states, boolean values, instead of declaring proper variables at class level. I am doing this because part of this data will be coming back to the server when the user wants to save it. I am just wondering if this approach is correct or as the object starts to grow I will have an impact on the performance or something like that. Just for clarity sake I am not storing a big amount of data in the object so the code is still very clear and the json very tidy.

```
"visibile_groups": {
                "V": false,
                "G": false,
                "A": false,
                "P": false
            },
```

instead of

```
v: boolean;
g: boolean;
a: boolean;
p: boolean;
```

Comment: Sorry mate, without showing the relevant code or at least an example, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: is you question something like this? If you use a class to model you data and use this class instance in the code, will it affect any performance???

Comment: updated! @DiabolicWords  This visible groups in the json is an optional data as this will not be coming from the server.

Comment: this looks more like asking for a code review and advice on code style than you have a problem that needs a solution.